# pandas vs sasdataset ,values are exact correct

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sas

Before reading into pandas, data is used in sasdataset. My data looks like

```
SNYDJCM--integer
740.19999981
```

After reading into pandas my data is changing as below

```
SNYDJCM--converting to float 
740.200000
```

How to get same value after reading into pandas dataframe
Steps followed:

1)

```
import pandas as pd
```

2)

```
pd.read_sas(path,format='sas7bdat',encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

Need your help

Answer (score 0):

Try import `SAS7BDAT` and casting your file before reading:

```
from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT
SAS7BDAT('FILENAME.sas7bdat')
df = pd.read_sas('FILENAME.sas7bdat',format='sas7bdat')
```

or use it to directly read the file:

```
from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT
sas_file = SAS7BDAT('FILENAME.sas7bdat')
df = sas_file.to_data_frame()
```

or use `pyreadstat` to read the file:

```
import pyreadstat
df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat('FILENAME.sas7bdat')
```

Comment: i dont have permission to install sas7bdat or pyreadstat
Could you please guide with out using the above packages

Answer (score 0):

First 740.19999981 is no integer 740 would be the nearest integer. But also when you round 740.19999981 down to 6 digits you will get 740.200000. I would sugest printing out with higher precision and see if it is really changed.

```
print("%.12f"%(x,))
```